# How does the scheduler of an operating system regain control from a process?

Tags: operating-system

-I would like to know, if we have a single core cpu and lets say that for a long time there are only cpu intesive processes (no I\O requests) how does the scheduler regain the control?

-I have read some stuff about timer interupts, i would like to know how is, the operating system, able to set this timer?

Comment: The timer is a hardware feature, so the OS (which has privileges to talk to I/O devices, via port or memory-mapped I/O) simply sends it commands saying how often to generate an interrupt.  The details are of course platform-dependent.  Then, as you say, when the interrupt is generated, the CPU transfers control to the interrupt handler, which is set up by the OS and can schedule a different process.

Comment: Platform depedent meaning that for every motherboard  the OS must know how to interact with the timer?

Comment: Not necessarily for every motherboard; e.g. all PC-compatible x86 machines follow common standards (with some variations).  But it will be different for a Mac M1 or for a Raspberry Pi or for a PDP-11 or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know, if we have a single core cpu and lets say that for a long time there are only cpu intesive processes (no I\O requests) how does the scheduler regain the control?

There's multiple choices:

a) It's a cooperative scheduler and gets control when the currently running task voluntarily or accidentally gives the scheduler control via. a kernel API function (which might be like `yield()` but could be anything that cause the currently running task to block - e.g. `read()`) or an exception (e.g. trying to access data that the kernel sent to swap space, causing a page fault where the page fault handler blocks the task until the data it needs is fetched from swap space). This can include the task crashing.

b) It's a preemptive scheduler that uses hardware (e.g. a timer) to ensure that kernel will gain control (and pass control to scheduler). Note that it might or might not be a timer (e.g. it could be a counter that counts the number of instructions executed, which has advantages for modern systems where CPU speed varies due to power management).

c) It's a "less cooperative/semi-preemptive" scheduler that opportunistically checks if a task switch should be done any time anything causes the kernel to gain control but doesn't explicitly use any hardware to ensure that kernel will gain control (e.g. so that things that seem unrelated to scheduling, like freeing memory, can cause a task switch).

d) It's a combination of the last 2 options - a preemptive scheduler that uses hardware to ensure that kernel will gain control; that (whenever kernel has control for any reason) opportunistically checks if a task switch can be done a little early to avoid a relatively expensive IRQ that would've occurred soon.

> I have read some stuff about timer interupts, i would like to know how is, the operating system, able to set this timer?

"The operating system" is a huge amount of stuff (e.g. includes things like data files for a help system and graphics for icons and ...). Typically there is a kernel which is able to do anything it likes with no restrictions; including accessing timer hardware directly.

The exact details of how a kernel would set a timer depends on which kind of timer it is. Note that there may be different types of timer to choose from (e.g. an 80x86 PC might have a PIT chip, an RTC chip, HPET, and a local APIC timer built into each CPU; where some are configured via. IO ports, some are configured via. memory mapped registers, and one may be configured via. special registers/MSRs built into the CPU; where each type of timer has different frequencies, precision, accuracy, capabilities, etc).